# Cordova Crosswalk: installation of Andoird-apk failed

Tags: android-studio, cordova, crosswalk

I'm using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3 to create android app with a build-in browser as standard webview in my app. 
Cordova can create very simple a android app without any problem. As I added crosswalk (latest version) in cordova, my export are in 2 versions: `arm64` and `x86_64`.

The problem is I cannot install both created apps on my android-device or emulator of android-studio.
I have 2 kind of errors:

**first:**

after importing the .apk in android-studio : `.*so` missing
[image: ross]

**second**
after try to running app: `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS`

[image]

can somebody help me to solve this problem? I also read some issues on github of crosswalk, but they are not interested to replay their issues.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `android-minSdkVersion` in `config.xml` to the latest version, like 28. Also just add this code in your `config.xml` and build the app via `cordova build android` again:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

After that there is a new apk-output, which names `debug.apk`. This apk is universal and can run on any devices.